# Simple code to add items to Picker not working

Tags: c#, maui

I am just learning MAUI and this sounds like a silly question but I am struggling to understand why it does not work.

I have just a button and a Picker on the form and I have to add items to the Picker on button click.

```cs
private void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pickAnimal.Items.Add("Monkey");
    pickAnimal.Items.Add("Horse");
    pickAnimal.SelectedIndex= 0;
}
```

If I click the button the Picker is not showing any items. If I move the same three lines of code to `MainPage` constructor like below it works fine.

```cs
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    pickAnimal.Items.Add("Monkey");
    pickAnimal.Items.Add("Horse");
    pickAnimal.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to use an ObservableCollection if you want the UI to refresh automatically

Comment: I have not heard from you for a couple of days. Please let me know if there is anything that I can help here. And you can use the solution ewerspej provided. It works well.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in reply. Thanks to Jason. Your answer was correct.  Thanks to Julian for explaining with sample code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an `ObservableCollection<string>` as the `ItemsSource` instead of directly trying to manipulate the Picker's `Items` read-only list, because the list isn't observable and as such only gets updated once.

This can be done in the code-behind, for example:

```cs
public class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; } = new();

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pickAnimal.ItemsSource = Items;
    }

    private void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Items.Add("Monkey");
        Items.Add("Horse");
        pickAnimal.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

***Note:** This will keep adding the same items again and again with each button click, which you probably don't want.*

You can find more information about [setting the ItemsSource property](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/picker#set-the-itemssource-property) of a Picker in the official documentation.